# inspect element within flash object

Tags: firefox-addon, firebug, watir-webdriver

I just want to click an element in the flash object. For that i tried to inspect element using firebug. But i cant find any option to inspect using firebug. im new to watir. Please suggest some solutions.

Thanks,
Saravana

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, both Watir and Firebug see Flash elements as a black box, they can not see what is inside.

Comment: thanks Filipin. Is there any other way to automate flash elements?

Comment: I remember hearing a few years ago that Flash has introduced API, but I do not remember hearing about tools using it. You can try http://www.sikuli.org/